# How can I use the dataset that I created used in VS2015

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, dataset, datasource

I used the UI to add a Data Source to my project.

The datasource is listed as `serverManagerDBDataSet` and when you open the triangle, it says "serverManagerTable" and when you open the triangle for that, you see the fields in the table

My question is how can I use this Data Source in my project (properly)?

```
string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + dbPath;
string cmdstr = "select * from serverManagerTable";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
con.Open();
OleDbDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
DataSet data = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(com);
da.Fill(data);
int i = data.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
```

I get an error saying the connection is already open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing two different reading mechanisms over one conection.  The first step is to take out the `ExecuteReader` and `Read` lines:

```
string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + dbPath;
string cmdstr = "select * from serverManagerTable";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
con.Open();
//OleDbDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
//reader.Read();
DataSet data = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(com);
da.Fill(data);
int i = data.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
```

Then wrap your database classes in `using` statements:

```
string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + dbPath;
string cmdstr = "select * from serverManagerTable";
DataSet data = new DataSet();

using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
using(OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con))
{
    con.Open();
    using(OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(com))
        da.Fill(data);
}
int i = data.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
```

The `using` statements ensure that your connections are closed in a timely manner if there is an exception loading the data.

To answer the question in the title, however, I'm supposing you should be using `serverManagerDBDataSet` instead of a plain `DataSet`

Comment: your code did work but was not sure why the Wizard created these 'Server Manager Components" in the toolbox

Comment: Honestly I haven't used typed data sets in years so I don't have a good answer to that one. I do know that early on they were treated as reusable "components" but that has largely gone a way with Entity Framework.